# Asynchronous transaction causes IllegalStateException

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, mariadb, hikaricp

there is an problem i currently have to deal with.
Iam trying to manage a slick2.0 transaction asynchronously. The reason for that are the futures i work with.

I wrote my own method to handle sessions asynchronously with slick:

```
def withAsyncTransaction[T](implicit block: Session => Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  val session = Database.forDataSource(dataSource).createSession()
  session.conn.setAutoCommit(false)
  block(session).recover {
    case e: Exception =>
      session.conn.rollback()
      session.conn.close()
      throw e
  }.map { v =>
    session.conn.commit()
    session.conn.close()
    v
  }
}
```

Iam using it like this(dataSource is injected):

```
withAsyncTransaction { implicit session =>
 ... CRUD
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
The datasource has been shutdown.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The datasource has been shutdown.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:62)
```

The error occurs sporadically and it does not depend on the connection pool. Same problem with boneCP. Does anybody have an idea?

Help would be kindly appreciated.
OliverKK

Comment: It's weird.  I'm not familiar with Slick but it seems that occasionally close() is being called on the DataSource itself and not the connection, is that possible?

Comment: After reading up on Slick, it appears using Futures with sessions is dangerous, so I'm not sure what you are trying to do is possible.  See the documentation [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1-RC1/connection.html), search for the word "escapes" for the warning.  I would recommend asking on the Slick forums.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what is causing the error that you're seeing, but I just learned from experience that combining futures, slick, and transactions is a recipe for headaches. The code you've written seems like it should work, except that there are parts of slick that assume that the autocommit setting is not being changed behind its back.

See the implementation of `withTransaction`: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/06ee4edade81633db10724a858f427deb563edfc/src/main/scala/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcBackend.scala#L476

It assumes that its private var `inTransaction` is up to date, and will set autocommit to true at the end of the operation if it doesn't think it was already in a transaction. This means that any code you write using the session you've created that calls `withTransaction` will commit the transaction and reset autocommit back to true. Now, this seems fine as long as you aren't calling `withTransaction`, but there are slick operations that call it internally when you might not expect it. For example, if you use `++=` to perform a bulk insert, it will call `withTransaction` and end up committing the transaction you've created and every statement you execute after that will be autocommitted.